# MySQL Dynamic string size of query helper with vsprintf (C++)

Tags: c++, mysql, string, stl

I have such function previously implemented in C and now moved to C++.

```
   int StmtExec(MYSQL *db, const char *query, va_list params) {
        char q[512];
        vsprintf(q, query, params);
        printf("Query %s\n", q);
        int result = mysql_query(db, q);
        if (result) {
            logger_error("%s\n", mysql_error(db));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The function creates `char q[512]` which size is limited by 512.
But I'd like unlimited (dynamic) query size with `std::string`
I still need to apply query as template that's why I need this `vsprintf`

I'm not quite good in C++ honestly... Is it possible?

I found this function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf and tried with C++ but it doesn't work with C++ string. Tried to use `q.c_str` but this doesn't compile too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You can do it in same way as one would do it in C, except you'd use `std::string` (or you could use `std::vector<char>` since it is used merely as a buffer) instead of `malloc`.

First call `vsnprintf` with nullptr, so that it doesn't write anything. Then use the returned size to allocate the buffer. Finally call `vsprintf`. But to use the argument list twice, you must duplicate it with `va_copy`. Example:

```
va_list params_copy;
va_copy(params_copy, params);
int len = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, query, params_copy);
va_end(params_copy);

std::string q(len + 1, '\0');    
vsprintf(q.data(), query, params);
```

That said, the standard C I/O API is tricky to use and prone to mistakes especially (but not exclusively) by the inexperienced.

The C++ iostreams are a safer alternative (but they aren't perfect either). C++20 will introduce a new `std::format` function that should offer best of both worlds.

> this first vsnprintf looks like some overhead

That's the C I/O API for you; take it or leave it. That said, I would expect the overhead to be tiny compared to the db query itself.

> Is it possible to reuse same string template with iostream

You can't use format strings with iostreams. Instead, can do something like:

```
query << "SELECT " << columns << " FROM " << table << " WHERE " << conditions;
```

Comment: this first `vsnprintf ` looks like some overhead... eh. Is it possible to reuse same string template with `iostream`?